# Once a floor boss is killed, does that level become bossless or does another boss appear with time?

Tags: danmachi

The dungeon walls create monsters constantly, but how about the floor bosses? Once a floor boss is killed, does that level become bossless or does another boss appear with time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When a boss is defeated, it will appear again after its recovery time.**

That means while the boss hasn't recovered yet then that level is technically bossless.

You can see this in season 1 episode 10 of Danmachi

> Bell and his teammates are having a hard time because of pass parade then Lili suggested to go in floor 18th since it is a safe zone. Welf is concerned about the boss in floor 17th but Lili said that they can make it since the boss is still "recovering"